# How to mock path like `module.Class`? using Python's Mock module?

Tags: python, mocking

How do I mock a class with this path `ablib.Pin`? And how do I mock the attributes of an instance off Pin? I would say it should work like this:

```
mock = MagicMock()                                                             
mock.Pin = MagicMock()                                            
mock.Pin.kernel_id = 'N21'                                                     
mock.Pin.set_value.return_value = True                                         
mock.Pin.get_value.return_value = 3                                            

modules = {
    'ablib': mock,                                                     
    'ablib.Pin': mock.Pin,                                                     
}

patcher = patch.dict('sys.modules', modules)                                   
patcher.start()
```

When I create a Pin instance I and call `get_value` or `set_value` I get a MockInstance instead of `True` or `3`.

```
>>> p = Pin()
>>> p.set_value(3)
<MagicMock name='mock.Pin().set_value(3)' id='47965968'>
>>> p.kernel_id
<MagicMock name='mock.Pin().kernel_id' id='49231056'>
```

When I call `kernel_id` directly on `Pin` I get the result I need.

```
>>> Pin.kernel_id
'N21'
```

How do I mock ablib.Pin in a way that I get the values I want from an instance ablib.Pin()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working version with minimal changes to your code:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock

mock = MagicMock()
mock.Pin().kernel_id = 'N21'
mock.Pin().set_value.return_value = True
mock.Pin().get_value.return_value = 3

modules = {
    'ablib': mock
}

patcher = patch.dict('sys.modules', modules)
patcher.start()
```

Test:

```
>>> import ablib
>>> ablib.Pin
<MagicMock name='mock.Pin' id='139917634188240'>
>>> ablib.Pin
<MagicMock name='mock.Pin' id='139917634188240'>
>>> ablib.Pin()
<MagicMock name='mock.Pin()' id='139917634233616'>
>>> ablib.Pin()
<MagicMock name='mock.Pin()' id='139917634233616'>
>>> p = ablib.Pin()
>>> p.set_value(3)
True
>>> p.kernel_id
'N21'
```

Notice that I've removed `mock.Pin = MagicMock()` and removed `mock.Pin` from the dictionary. New MagicMock instance is created by default when you access existing MagicMock attribute or call it. The same instance will be returned next time you do that action. So there is no need to explicitly create MagicMock for `mock.Pin` (for Pin class), `mock.Pin()` (for Pin instance) and to register them with `patch.dict()`. Just registering `mock` is enough.

Thanks to `patch.dict()` it works even when module `ablib` doesn't exist. I believe that it is not possible to achieve with `patch()` and `patch.object()`. Nevertheless for real unit-testing I use `patch()` to mock a class and `patch.object()` to mock attributes of an instance for some particular test or group of tests. I have not been in a situation when I needed to mock a whole module, but I'm quite new to unit-testing and Python.